# How to install laravel/cashier 6.0 in Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

everyone.
Recently I have upgraded my laravel 5.2 project to laravel 5.8.
But I want to use laravel/cashier 6.0 in laravel 5.8.
I have installed it by "composer require laravel/cashier:6.0" but it throws error something like this.
[image]

Is there any way to do this for me?
Thank you.

Comment: Please share more details, for example about the rest of your `composer.json` and your debugging attempts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `composer.json`, change Carbon version to `1.26.3`. Next, run `composer update` (not `composer install`.)

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I have added this and ran composer update. "nesbot/carbon": "1.32.0 as 1.25", and the carbon installed. But later when I tried to install laravel/cashier:6.0 it throws another error. https://prnt.sc/spl736

Comment: Please do **not** install a later package using something like `1.32.0 as 1.25` - if there is some incompatibility provided by the package's `composer.json` there's a good reason for that

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Laravel Cashier requires Carbon v1, which is deprecated in Laravel 5.8
If you may use Laravel 5.7 things should go different.
Anyway both Laravel 5.7 and 5.8 are old versions with no long term support, so in that sense, best choice should be Laravel 6
Regards.